# outliers removal on InfluxDB, Grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb, outliers, quantile

the built-in function of Influx to compute the quantiles from the given data shows on its documentation that the quantile is computed given the tag which means that it outputs multiple tables based on that tag. While applying it for my case, it wasn’t doing it that way it was only showing on display a single output coming from only one tag value out of the three tag values that I have.

Basically, what I am trying to do is to exclude outliers from my data but I am only able to do this to all the data which I don’t really want it that way. I need to find a way to group the data per that tag (which I do), then compute Q1 and Q3 accordingly for each tag value and automatically filter the data using [Q1-3*IQR, Q3+3*IQR]. But I am stuck on how to do this. I am trying to avoid manual approaches as much as possible.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Konstantinos Azas